# setmemwindow in hpux giving not enough space error

Tags: hp-ux

I m trying to run three different services in my hpux 11.31 servr which loads different shared objects, for that i have enabled "setmemwindow" and set the max_mem_window as "3", but i m able to start services only in two different windows . if my trying the third it is giving the below error :

```
map text for library</FIN_BE/BOBUA_BE/Finacle/FC/app/prodbase/exe/rf_gensrc.so>: mmap(0x0, 0x475ffa0, 0x5, 0x41, 15, 0x0) **returns Not enough space**.]

shmmax value -> 214748364800
```

starting services as below :

```
setmemwindow -i1010 ./startSERV1 --> this is working fine 
setmemwindow -i20 ./startSERV2  --> this is giving error

/etc/services.window :

datebase1 20
database2 30
database3 40
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by enabling memory windows in HPUX, you can get more details from the below link https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/setmemwindow.1M.html

start the service using setmemwindow : ex: `setmemwindow -i1010 <service_start_script>`